# Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Nexus_5_API_25 was killed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ide

I recently installed android studio. I am running android studio 3.1.4. I am facing an issue in which I have not start android studio emulator. When I start emulator then error occur "Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Nexus_5_API_25 was killed." and popup shown on screen is "Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1[enter image description here]"

Please see this image
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7BsP.png

Please resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you give more Detail about this..or follow some video tutorials that will resolve your problem.
I have same issue i follow some tutorials that solved my this issue from start to end.